# len() vs .size(0) when looping through DataLoader samples

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I came across this on github (snippet from [here](https://github.com/E-Renshaw/ping-pong-gan/blob/master/dcgan.py)):

```py
(...)
for epoch in range(round):
        for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
            ############################
            # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
            ###########################
            # train with real
            netD.zero_grad()
            real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
            batch_size = real_cpu.size(0)
            label = torch.full((batch_size,), real_label, device=device)
            (...)
```

Would replacing `batch_size = real_cpu.size(0)` with `batch_size = len(data[0])` give the same effect? (or maybe at least with `batch_size = len(real_cpu)`?) Reason why I'm asking is that iirc the official PyTorch tutorial incorporated `len(X)` when displaying training progress during the loop `for (X, y) in dataloader:` etc. so I was wondering if the two methods are equivalent for displaying the number of 'samples' in the 'current' batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working with data where batch size is the first dimension then you can interchange `real_cpu.size(0)` with `len(real_cpu)` or with `len(data[0])`.
However when working with some models like LSTMs you can have batch size at second dimension, and in such case you couldn't go with `len`, but rather `real_cpu.size(1)` for example